# jQuery get id of dynamic id link

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm new to jquery and have looked around all day but can't resolve what's a very simple idea :)

Here's the test code:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#transgenic_div').click(function(){
        var selected_transgenic_id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(selected_transgenic_id);          
    });

});
```

html:

```
<div id="transgenic_div">
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="56">item number 56</a></p>
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="57">item number 57</a></p> etc
</div>
```

This just gives the alert "tansgenic_div"
I'm trying to pass the selected id to another function - but for now just testing with the alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you don't really want to match the main `<div>` but the inner links:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#transgenic_div p a').click(function(){
        var selected_transgenic_id = $(this).attr("id");
        // Or simply: this.id
        alert(selected_transgenic_id);          
    });
});
```

(BTW, valid IDs cannot start with a digit unless you are using HTML 5.)

**Full working example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#transgenic_div p a').click(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});//--></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="transgenic_div">
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="56">item number 56</a></p>
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="57">item number 57</a></p> etc
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried $('#transgenic_div p a').click(function(){ and every variation I can think of and the button fails to work

Comment: @steven - Well, the code works. I'm pretty sure you have an error somewhere else but with *fails to work* as only description the problem is hard to diagnose.

Comment: dynamic code from a jquery function (doesn't work):
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="transgenic_12">Tg(vmat2:GFP)</a></p>

hard coded (works):
<p><a class="transgenic_button" id="transgenic_56">item number 56</a></p>

Is this because the dynamic code is delayed?

The full code is:


$(document).ready(function(){
  updateTransgenic();
  updateRegionTransgenic(); // this creates the dynamic links with php backend script
  $('#transgenic_div p').click(function(e) {
      var selected_transgenic_id = $(e.target).attr("id"); // or e.target.id
      alert(selected_transgenic_id);
  });
 });

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the ID from the [target/source element](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) of the click event:

```
$('#transgenic_div').click(function(e){
    var selected_transgenic_id = $(e.target).attr("id"); // or e.target.id
    alert(selected_transgenic_id);          
});
```

Also, [IDs should not start with numbers in HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), I would suggest applying a prefix.

If you want to match only anchors using this technique, you can do so like this:

```
$('#transgenic_div').click(function(e){
    var t = e.target;
    if(t.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
        var selected_transgenic_id = $(t).attr("id"); // or t.id
        alert(selected_transgenic_id);   
    }       
});
```

Comment: This technique is called *event delegation*.

Comment: actually not quite perfect..
because of the
      $('#transgenic_div').click(function(e){
clicking anywhere in the div gives an alert. I guess
  $('#transgenic_div p a').click(function(e){
should work but it doesn't

Comment: @steven - edited, you really should read about event delegation, as it has many applications. Here's a decent resource: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Comment: great - works well - thanks both for pointing out event delegation - I'll read up on it now...